# How to post Jenkins job output to slack notification

Tags: jenkins

im trying to post Jenkins job script output to slack notification: but i cant able to access the output in slack notification setting.

other than `/env-vars.html/` the variables here i can't able to access any other variable.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no support to get the variables other than env vars in Jenkins. We can use "Environment Injector" plugin but I am not sure about that plugin.

For your case you can create a "Pipeline" with the below scripted pipeline

```
node('JENKINS_NODE') {
    git([url: 'GITHUB_REPO_URL', branch: 'BRANCH'])
    def getResult

    stage ('Execute Script') {
      getResult = sh(
        script: "python test.py",
        returnStdout: true,
      )
    }
    stage ('Send Slack Notification') {
      slackSend channel: '#YOUR_SLACK_CHANNEL', color: 'good', message: getResult'
    }
}
```